# Cumulative sum and substract over time when condition are met

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, shift, cumsum

I have a dataframe with IOT sensors data. What I'm trying to get a humidity score over time when a condition is met.
Let's say that my df looks like this:

```
Day       Flat    Humidity
31/12     1       False
01/01     1       True
02/01     1       True
03/01     1       True
04/01     1       True
05/01     1       False
06/01     1       False
07/01     1       True
08/01     1       True
09/01     1       False
10/01     1       False
11/01     1       False
12/01     1       False
13/01     1       False
14/01     1       False
15/01     1       True
01/01     2       False
02/01     2       False
03/01     2       True
04/01     2       False
```

What I would like to get is the humidity score which is the cumulative sum of when Humidity = True. The thing I do not manage to get is when Humidity = False, I do not want the sum to start from 0 but subtract 1 from the previous value when it's not equal to 0.

In my example, it should look like this:

```
Day       Flat    Humidity    Score
31/12     1       False       0
01/01     1       True        1
02/01     1       True        2
03/01     1       True        3
04/01     1       True        4
05/01     1       False       3
06/01     1       False       2
07/01     1       True        3
08/01     1       True        4
09/01     1       False       3
10/01     1       False       2
11/01     1       False       1
12/01     1       False       0
13/01     1       False       0
14/01     1       False       0
15/01     1       True        1
01/01     2       False       0
02/01     2       False       0
03/01     2       True        1
04/01     2       False       0
```

As you can see, on the 05/01 when the Humidity = False, I do not want the count to start from 0 but be the number of previous row - 1; in my case 4-1 = 3.
Also, this needs to be computed by flat and the score cannot be a value below 0.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `cumsum` per group, and then correct for the points that went below the minimum:

```
s = df['Humidity'].mul(2).sub(1).groupby(df['Flat']).cumsum()
mask = s.mask(df['Humidity']|s.gt(0))
corr = mask.groupby(df['Flat']).ffill().fillna(0, downcast='infer')
df['Score'] = s-corr
```

output (with intermediates):

```
      Day  Flat  Humidity  expected  raw_score  mask  correction  Score
0   01/01     1      True         1          1   NaN           0      1
1   02/01     1      True         2          2   NaN           0      2
2   03/01     1      True         3          3   NaN           0      3
3   04/01     1      True         4          4   NaN           0      4
4   05/01     1     False         3          3   NaN           0      3
5   06/01     1     False         2          2   NaN           0      2
6   07/01     1      True         3          3   NaN           0      3
7   08/01     1      True         4          4   NaN           0      4
8   09/01     1     False         3          3   NaN           0      3
9   10/01     1     False         2          2   NaN           0      2
10  11/01     1     False         1          1   NaN           0      1
11  12/01     1     False         0          0   0.0           0      0
12  13/01     1     False         0         -1  -1.0          -1      0
13  14/01     1     False         0         -2  -2.0          -2      0
14  15/01     1      True         1         -1   NaN          -2      1
15  01/01     2     False         0         -1  -1.0          -1      0
16  02/01     2     False         0         -2  -2.0          -2      0
17  03/01     2      True         1         -1   NaN          -2      1
18  04/01     2     False         0         -2  -2.0          -2      0
```

Comment: Hi mozway, thanks a lot for your answers. However your solution does not work in some cases but I'm not able to find the pattern..  In some cases, the score does not decrease by 1 but goes immediately to 0 when condition is false.. By anyway I will investigate! Thanks a lot

Comment: @AllanLC interesting, can you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

From your `DataFrame`, first we get the first element of each group as we don't want to start with `-1` if the `Humidity` is `False` :

```py
df['first_elt'] = (df.groupby(['Flat'], as_index=False)['Humidity'].nth(0))
```

Then, we can change the boolean values of `Humidity` to `1` and `-1`, and `0` in the case of `Humidity` is `False` like so :

```py
df.loc[df.Humidity == True, 'Humidity_tmp'] = 1
df.loc[df.Humidity == False, 'Humidity_tmp'] = -1
df.loc[df.first_elt == False, 'Humidity_tmp'] = 0
```

```
    Day    Flat Humidity    first_elt   Humidity_tmp
0   01/01   1   True        True        1.0
1   02/01   1   True        NaN         1.0
2   03/01   1   True        NaN         1.0
3   04/01   1   True        NaN         1.0
4   05/01   1   False       NaN         -1.0
5   06/01   1   False       NaN         -1.0
6   07/01   1   True        NaN         1.0
7   08/01   1   True        NaN         1.0
8   01/01   2   False       False       0.0
9   02/01   2   True        NaN         1.0
10  03/01   2   False       NaN         -1.0
```

To finish, we use a `cumsum` with the `groupby` on `Flat` to get the expected result :

```py
df['Score'] = df.groupby('Flat')['Humidity_tmp'].cumsum()
```

Output :

```
    Day   Flat  Humidity    first_elt   Humidity_tmp    Score
0   01/01   1   True        True        1.0             1.0
1   02/01   1   True        NaN         1.0             2.0
2   03/01   1   True        NaN         1.0             3.0
3   04/01   1   True        NaN         1.0             4.0
4   05/01   1   False       NaN         -1.0            3.0
5   06/01   1   False       NaN         -1.0            2.0
6   07/01   1   True        NaN         1.0             3.0
7   08/01   1   True        NaN         1.0             4.0
8   01/01   2   False       False       0.0             0.0
9   02/01   2   True        NaN         1.0             1.0
10  03/01   2   False       NaN         -1.0            0.0
```

The full code :

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""
Day,Flat,Humidity
01/01,1,True
02/01,1,True
03/01,1,True
04/01,1,True
05/01,1,False
06/01,1,False
07/01,1,True
08/01,1,True
01/01,2,False
02/01,2,True
03/01,2,False
"""), sep=',')
df['first_elt'] = (df.groupby(['Flat'], as_index=False)['Humidity'].nth(0))
df.loc[df.Humidity == True, 'Humidity_tmp'] = 1
df.loc[df.Humidity == False, 'Humidity_tmp'] = -1
df.loc[df.first_elt == False, 'Humidity_tmp'] = 0
df['Score'] = df.groupby('Flat')['Humidity_tmp'].cumsum()
df
```

Comment: Oups, I just saw that I made a mistake, I am on it ;)

Comment: Thanks tlentali, however your code does not work when the DF start with Humidity = False for instance since the score will have negative value and start the sum from it. Do you know how to make the same thing but with the condition that the minimum value for score is 0 ?

Comment: Hi @AllanLC ! I change the answer, does it works well for you now ?

Comment: Hi tlentali, I get this error when running your code: ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Comment: I added the full code at the end of the answer, can you try that please ?

Comment: Hi tlentali, thanks a lot for your effort but unfortunately I still get negative value when Humidity = False and hence when it is TRUE, the sum start from the negative value

Comment: I think that @mozway found the correct answer !

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
import numpy as np
df['Humidity2']=np.where(df['Humitidy']==False,np.nan,1)


df['ScoreTemp']=df.groupby('Flat')['Humidity2'].transform(lambda s:s.where(s.ffill().isnull(), s.fillna(-1))).fillna(0)

df['Score']=df.groupby('Flat')['ScoreTemp'].transform('cumsum')

df.drop(['ScoreTemp','Humidity2'],axis=1,inplace=True)

df.loc[(df['Humitidy']==False) & (df['Score']<0),'Score']=0
df.loc[(df['Humitidy']==True) & (df['Score']<0),'Score']=1
df

df
```

- 'Humdity2' where all false from Humidity are converted to NaNs
- 'ScoreTemp' where we fill with -1 all Humidity2 not starting with False for a given Flat, otherwise fill with 0
- 'Score' doing the cumsum on that ScoreTemp calculated column grouped by Flat
- Then drop the constructed columns

Edit:

Workaround for both cases when score becomes negative and Humidity is False -> force to 0.
When score becomes negative and Humidity is True -> force to 1

Comment: Hi @Daniel, Thanks a lot for your answer. It works but the issue is that when Humidity = False for a long period of time, the score becomes negative; and when the condition is met again, the sum start from a negative number where it should start from 0. Do you know any work around for this?

Comment: I havent seen thst on my test data - could you provide an updated inut example where these False values give you that result ?

Comment: Ok, just edited with a workaround in both scenarios when score gets negative ...it's not very clean as many workarounds here but let me know if it works!